# When I add another value and refresh the page its not retaining first value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

When I add the first value in the text box it's updating in drop down when I refresh its retaining the value due to local storage. However when I add another value and refresh the page its not retaining first value.

How can I retain more than one value in the drop down after I make a page refresh?

http://jsfiddle.net/d3xtyv89/

```js
dropdown.options = function(data) {
  var self = this;
  var newOptions = "";  //create one objec to save new options

  $.each(data, function(ix, val) {
    newOptions += '<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>';
    // data.push(option);
  });
  self.html(newOptions);
}
```

Comment: Is kendo grid really necessary in the demo? It distracts from the issue. Better localise the problem to bare minimum and then it's way simpler to fix.

Comment: @AlivetoDie can you explain so that in future I can learn it myself

Comment: did it worked or not?

Comment: @AlivetoDie hey it didnt work :(